How to Calculate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x^{\top}y$ given random vectors $x$ and $y$?
Given random variable $X$ and Gaussian random variable $Y$ with zero mean and unit variance ($X$ is independent of $Y$), $\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is i.i.d. sampled from $X$ and $\boldsymbol{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is i.i.d. sampled from $Y$. In $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have the following equation almost sure
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{x}^{\top}\boldsymbol{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\overset{\text{a.s.}}{=}
\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0
\end{align}
How about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\boldsymbol{x}^{\top}\boldsymbol{y}$?

Assuming $X$ have finite second moment, $$Z_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i Y_i$$ has zero mean and variance $\mathbf{Var}(Z_n)=\mathbf{E}[X^2]$. So,

By the central limit theorem, $Z_n$ converges in distribution to the normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\mathbf{E}[X^2]$.

However, $Z_n$ does not converge either in almost-sure sense or in probability.


